# Why Node.js CLI app hangs after completion till break with Ctrl-C?

Tags: node.js, node-commander, inquirerjs

I've a simple Node.js command line program that uses `commander` and `inquirer` for taking command line inputs. It then connects to MongoDB Atlas to carryout its operations in `index.js` file, and after connection to DB is closed, it just hangs there till process is broken with `Ctrl-C`. Even if I call an empty function with no connection to DB, it still does the same. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const program = require('commander');
const { prompt } = require('inquirer');
const {addProduct, findProduct, findOrder} = require('./index');

const questions = [
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'id',
        message: 'Product ID'
    }
];

program
    .version('1.0.0')
    .description('Test program to create records');

program
    .command('search')
    .alias('s')
    .description('Find a product by ProductID')
    .action(() => {
        prompt(questions). then((answers) => {
            findProduct(answers)
        })
    }); 

program.parse(process.argv);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I've tried both `program.prase()` and `program.parseAsync()` with the same result.

Comment: Might need to see what `findProduct` does

Comment: Not related to `findProduct`, if I take that out and just prints `Hello World`, it still hangs.

Comment: What versions of `commander` and `inquirer` are you using?

Comment: No problem here using the latest `commander` and `inquirer` with code updated to use ES modules ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/node-js-forked-bvhqg5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Version: "commander": "^9.4.0", "inquirer": "8.2.4"
Node version: v16.15.1

Comment: You need to open a new terminal and run `node src/index.js s`

Comment: I can confirm that it runs in codesandbox, but not on my mac with M1 processor.

Comment: Works fine for me on my Intel Mac. I literally ran `yarn init -y`, added `"type": "module"` to `package.json`, ran `yarn add commander inquirer`, put the contents from the sandbox link into `cmd.js`, ran `node cmd.js s`, was prompted for `Product ID`, entered anything and it said _"Hello, World!"_ and exited.

Comment: Thanks @Phil. I can confirm that creating a minimal program like this does run and ends gracefully. Your comment have helped divert my attention to elsewhere in the program. Much appreciated!